# Error: value too long for field: source maximum length is:131072

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Error: value too long for field: source maximum length is:131072

Getting above error while deploying Lwc through VScode.

Little help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share a bit about your source code? Like size of your source code?

Comment: You're limited to 131072 bytes per file. Split your code into multiple components/script files.

Comment: Looks like this already has an answer. Your file size is too large. Try to break this further to avoid the error!